# C# nuget dependency folder

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

By default, all dlls from nuget deps are copied to bin/Release or bin/Debug folder alongside with executable and its dependencies from solution. Some packages produce a lot of dlls, which doesn't look nice.
Is there any way to set a subfolder for nuget binaries? Like bin/Release/deps.

Comment: It's achieveable, but only with a lot of fiddling about, you've got to tell the build process to copy the DLL's into the sub folder, and tell your main app (and anything else that uses them) where they are (I think via the project config).   Not sure its worth the effort!  Why would anyone be looking in the programs folder anyway!

Comment: @cjb110 when a solution contains multiple executables, and each one has it's own configs, it would be nice to have only useful files in the root directory, while having all deps in a subfolder. I know I can prefix all with underscore to top all needed files, but that's also not nice :S